# Finding random x,y coordinates in a figure where you know the boundary

Tags: random, coordinates, figure, boundary

The goal is to find coordinates in a figure with an unknown shape. What IS known is a list of coordinates of the boundary of that figure, for example:

`boundary = [(0,0),(1,0),(2,0),(3,0),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(2,3),(2,2),(1,2),(1,3),(0,3),(0,2),(0,1]`

which would look something like this:

[Square with a gab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSqAH.png)

This is a very basic example and i'd like to do it with very larg lists of very different kinds of figures.

The question is how to get a random coordinate that lies within the figure WITHOUT hardcoding the anything about the shape of the figure, because this will be unknown at the beginning? Is there a way to know for certain or is making an estimate the best option? How would I implement an estimate like that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide an example of what you have trried. Read [ask] and providing a [mre]. Also make sure you have tagged this correctly with the language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is tentative answer. You sample numbers in two steps.

Before, do preparation work - split your figure into simple elementary objects. In your case you split it into rectangles, often people triangulate and split it into triangles.

So you have number `N` of simple objects, each with area of A<sub>i</sub> and total area A = Sum(A<sub>i</sub>).

First sampling step - select which rectangle you pick point from.
In some pseudocode

```
r = randomU01(); // random value in [0...1) range
for(i in N) {
    r = r - A_i/A;
    if (r <= 0) {
        k = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

So you picked up one rectangle with index `k`, and then just sample point uniformly in that rectangle

```
x = A_k.dim.x * randomU01();
y = A_k.dim.y * randomU01();

return (x + A_k.lower_left_corner.x, y + A_k.lower_left_corner.y);
```

And that is it. Very similar technique for triangulated figure.

Rectangle selection could be optimized by doing binary search or even more complicated [alias method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_method)

UPDATE

If your boundary is generic, then the only good way to go is to triangulate your polygon using any good library out there (f.e. [Triangle](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html)), then select one of the triangles based on area (step 1), then sample uniformly point in the triangle using two random U01 numbers r1 and r2,

```
P = (1 - sqrt(r1)) * A + (sqrt(r1)*(1 - r2)) * B + (r2*sqrt(r1)) * C
```

i.e., in pseudocode

```
r1 = randomU01();
s1 = sqrt(r1);
r2 = randomU01();

x = (1.0-s1)*A.x + s1*(1.0-r2)*B.x + r2*s1*C.x;
y = (1.0-s1)*A.y + s1*(1.0-r2)*B.y + r2*s1*C.y;

return (x,y);
```

Comment: I get where you're going, but I don't yet see how to get rectangles with your only knowledge being te coordinates of the boundary. You could iterate over all coordinates of the boudary and make rectangles of width 1 and go down to the first boundary it comes across, but idk if that's efficient.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try implementing it now!